# load google and facebook to iFrame

Tags: php, jquery, iframe

hi i have a problem with iFrame, i have to create an application which want to enter any address to text box and the site will load to iFrame, but the problem with some sites like facebook and google, they didn't load to the iFrame, i use PHP for create this, anyone know how can facebok and gogle load into iFrame with their styles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that. 
Including another site inside your iframe could be considered an attack (you could modify their ui using JS, or steal clicks or other similar not-so-good things), so they're protected against it.

*Edit*

I would suggest you read up on [framekillers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framekiller)

Comment: this i not for hacking, other all sites are allow for iframe loading but google and fb not, is there a php function for load this ?

Comment: I'm not saying you want to hack them dude, I'm saying you could, and that's why they're prottecting, learn to read before down voting please.

Comment: i show the ites like proxyninja... are doing these thing how they doing this ?

Comment: Added a link to the answer, check it, maybe your answer is there.

Comment: Deleteman, I downvoted the answer because you cannot modify the UI via JavaScript; the cross-origin policy prevents this. You can overlay elements on top of the iframe, but that would be a function of the DOM and CSS, not JavaScript.

Comment: yes but how this implement on proxyninja, they access google within iframe

Answer (score 1):

Both Google and Facebook make use of the [`X-Frame-Options` HTTP response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header) in order to prevent their sites from being framed by a site on another domain.

X-Frame-options is only recognized by "newer" browsers. But don't get excited just yet, there are way to prevent frame in those browsers as well. Jeff Atwood (co-founder of Stack Overflow and the Stack Exchange network) has [talks about frame busting](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/06/we-done-been-framed.html) on his blog.

The reason websites *need* to prevent framing is that iframes (and frames) allow for a malicious attack known as [clickjacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking). Clickjacking is:

> a malicious technique of tricking a Web user into clicking on something different to what the user perceives they are clicking on, thus potentially revealing confidential information or taking control of their computer while clicking on seemingly innocuous web pages.